# Uploading an image to google cloud storage from camera directly

Tags: javascript, object, post, google-cloud-storage, image-uploading

I am new to capturing an image from a camera and uploading it directly to google cloud storage using REST API and JavaScript. 
Is there any documentation available I can use.
I tired the documentation provided by Google but it is not pointing me to anywhere yet. 
Can someone point me in right direction?

I am trying to capture an image from robot and upload it to cloud so that I can perform image analysis on it.

Here is the code below.

```
function _TakePicture(data) {
    var base64String = data.Result.Base64;
    misty.Debug("Picture taken");

    // Upload the image to Imgur!
    uploadImage(base64String);
}

function uploadImage(imageData) {
    var jsonBody = {
        "image": imageData,
        "type" : "base64",
    };

    let accessToken = misty.Get("googleAccessToken");

    misty.SendExternalRequest("POST", accessToken, "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/misty-face/o?uploadType=media&name=mypic.jpg");
}
```

Comment: The REST API for GCS programming is available here ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/ .... I am thinking that to allow us to assist you more, you might want to add more details.  What have you tried?  What programming environment are you going to use to make the calls?

Comment: @Kolban  I am trying to capture an image from robot and upload that image to google cloud futher analysis.

see the updated original question

Comment: @sachin, are you planning to upload the images in stream ?

Comment: @Vilkram Shinde. I have created media bucket and I want to upload image when TakePicture function is called.

Comment: Which libraries are you using to capture the image?

Comment: @Miguel I am using inbuit function of the robot to take picture and I want to upload that picture to GCS. you can find the documents over here. https://docs.mistyrobotics.com/misty-ii/rest-api/api-reference/#takepicture

Comment: From your code, what I can see is that when the image is taken you get the data as a base64 string. You should first convert this string into an actual image and then you'll be able to upload that image into GCS using the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) for example